# (CAKEPHP) Highlight a row in a Product table for a comparison condition (no hovering needed)

Tags: javascript, php, css, cakephp, highlighting

How  do you find the right approach to getting this comparison to work? I've tried all kinds of approaches. I even used ids, but they don't respond. If I do this "gumboots" string check though, it does work. "gumboots" was just a string value for a product name that existed somewhere on the table. This is how I know I do not need PHP at all for this, despite the tables displayed in PHP in the Index view below. Any idea? I would appreciate it.

Here's the javascript

```
$('#example tbody tr td').each(function() 
{

                 var p_no_in_stock = parseInt(document.getElementById('p_no_in_stock')).value;
                 var p_reorder_quantity = parseInt(document.getElementById('p_reorder_quantity')).value;


//if ($product['Product']['p_no_in_stock'].val() < $product['Product']['p_reorder_quantity'].val())
if ($(this).text() == "gumboots") 
//if ($(this).p_no_in_stock < $(this).p_reorder_quantity)
{
//$("#row_" +" td").effect("highlight", {}, 1500);
$(this).parent().attr('style','background:red');
$(this).parent().css('font-weight','bold');

} 

});
```

And this is the application in a View called Products.index

```
<div class="active">

        <h2><?php echo __('Products'); ?></h2>

        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered" id ="example">

            <tr>

                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('p_name', 'Name'); ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('category_name', 'Category'); ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('p_no_in_stock','No. in Stock'); ?></th>
                <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('p_reorder_quantity', 'Re-order Quantity'); ?></th>
                <th class="actions"><?php echo __('Actions'); ?></th>
            </tr>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
                <tr>

                    <td><?php echo h($product['Product']['p_name']); ?></td>
                    <td> <?php echo $this->Html->link($product['Category']['category_name'], 
                    array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'view', $product['Category']['id'])); ?>
                    </td>      
                    <td id = "p_no_in_stock" type ="number" ><?php echo h($product['Product']['p_no_in_stock']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td id ="p_reorder_quantity" type ="number" ><?php echo h($product['Product']['p_reorder_quantity']); ?>&nbsp;</td>
                    <td class="actions">
                        <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('View'), array('action' => 'view', $product['Product']['id']), array('class' => 'btn btn-mini')); ?>
                        <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Edit'), array('action' => 'edit', $product['Product']['id']), array('class' => 'btn btn-mini')); ?>
                        <?php echo $this->Form->postLink(__('Delete'), array('action' => 'delete', $product['Product']['id']), array('class' => 'btn btn-mini'), __('Are you sure you want to delete # %s?', $product['Product']['id'])); ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
        </table>
```

Thanks in advance.

SOLVED Problem

Remove type number

Edit the tr tag to

```
<tr class ="item-row"> after foreach part.
```

Comment: let me see if I understand what you are trying to do here.
so you are rending a table and you want to search a particular string with in it. if you find it in any of the rows, you want to high-light that row to indicate the match.

s that correnct?

Comment: No, I want to highlight rows with products where the comparison of one number called "p_no_in_stock" to be less than "p_reorder_quantity". Each product has these attributes. I just wanted to indicate the simple string condition worked with highlighting function and I expected the comparison to work with it.

Comment: Ah ok, got it. So you want to highlight rows where you have less products in stock compared to those that need to be re-ordered. I'll post something for you to try below, give me a minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, a few things you need to change:

1. Remove that `type="number"` attribute from your td-tag. The type-attribute only applies to input-tags
2. User classes in place of ids (for p_no_in_stock and p_reorder_quantity). IDs are intended for unique items (aka: appear on the screen only once), while classes do not have this limitation. And since you are generating td's in a loop... chances are pretty high that you will have more than 1 of these.

Take a look at this this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FTh4m/ to see a working some working code (it assumes you have jQuery on the page).

If you're not too familiar with jQuery, I can explain what each line is doing.

---

As for why what you currently have doesn't work... the explanation in rather long, but I'll do my best to explain:

The select you have (`$('#example tbody tr td')`) is going to return an array of ALL td's on the screen.
And when you do `document.getElementById()`, it will only grab the first instance of that ID that it finds in the DOM (I think IE actually search bottom-up, but that's a story for another day).
So in that each-loop, you are actually going through every single td on the page, not just the td's you care about.

A pro-tip for the future, when trying to debug this type of client-side JS, open the [Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) (or [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/), if you're a FireFox kind of person) and start testing your jQuery selectors in the console.

Comment: Thank you very much. I adapted it, and perfectly working like a charm. Kudos to you. I'll edit mine to show where to do it for anyone else who wishes to know.